# synch gs bucket with s3 bucket (lambda style)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, aws-lambda

Simple problem, i have got a google bucket which gets content 3 times a day from an external provider. I want to fetch this content as soon as it arrives and push it onto a S3 bucket. I have been able to achieve this via running my python scripts as a cron job. But I have to provide high availability and such if i follow this route.

My idea was to set this up in aws lambda, so I don't have to sweat the infrastructure limitations. Any pointers on this marriage between gs and lambda. I am not a native Node speaker so any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have a way to notify your `Lambda` about new content in the google bucket?

Comment: Nopes.. not in my control..but I can check lets say hourly to get the list of keys...compare with dynamodb and pull down updated files

Comment: I'd recommend pushing the acquired list of files to `SNS Topic` and have your file manipulation `Lambda` subscribe to this topic. I suggest you publish each file as a new message to that `SNS Topic` so your files get processed in parallel. Once your Lambda receives a message, it can copy the file from your google bucket to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCS can send object notifications when an object is created/updated. You can catch the notifications (which are HTTP post requests) by a simple web app hosted on GAE, and then handle the file transfer to S3. Highly available, event driven solution.

Comment: late addition: you have to be the owner on the gcs bucket to achieve this though